# How to select Direct Descendants of a Direct Descendant

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the direct `<tr>'s` descendants of a the first direct `<table>` descendant of the `<body>`.

I am currently doing the following:

```
$("body > table:first > tr")
```

but this is returning 0 elements.

What would be the correct way to do it?

Note: There are no class or id in any of the elements. ( :( )

Comment: I don't think there is a `:first` selecor in css

Comment: Yeah, this isn't even CSS. Not sure why it was tagged as such.

Comment: I'm not an expert in CSS, I was just basing myself from examples that I found online, didn't know it wasn't css

Comment: And this is why I hate that jQuery says it uses "CSS selectors"... all it does is confuse people.

Comment: Also, if you look at that link carefully, it doesn't describe what your code is doing at all. That should have been an indication that that was not the correct place to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tables, there is another selector between the `table` and the `tr` elements: `tbody`.

So, what you need is this:

```
$("body > table:first > tbody > tr")
```

Comment: +1 This is mostly correct, just needs to be `table:first-child`.

Comment: The first `table` direct descendant of `body` *is* `body > table:first`, not `table:first-child` - that would only match if the table were the very first child of `body`. (This isn't CSS; the question was tagged wrongly.)